# Refactoring setState with callback for functional component

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit unsure how to change this code for use in a functional component. I've edited all my other setStates, but this one has two states updated followed by a callback function, so I don't know how to deal with this situation. Any ideas?

```
const handleSortAlpha = () => {
  setState({
    sortalphaStatus: sortalphaStatus === 'A-Z' ? 'Z-A' : 'A-Z',
    sorttypeStatus: 'alpha',
  },
  () => {
    inputToOutput();
  });
};
```

Comment: With [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), callbacks are replaced by the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. You will add the state variable to the `useEffect`'s dependency array, and it will run when the variable changes.

Comment: I am new to Hooks and currently only know useState. I will have to look into the useEffect hook as I also have some other setStates where only one state is set but there is still a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [alphaStatus,setalphaStatus] = useState()
const [type,settypeStatus] = useState()
```

and the function:

```
changeStates = () => {
  const value = 'A-Z' ? 'Z-A' : 'A-Z'
  setalphaStatus(value);
  settypeStatus(alpha);
  inputToOutput();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the callback.

Comment: I have a callback because the state updating is asynchronous. Is that correct?

Comment: Without knowing what `inputToOutput` actually looks like it's impossible to know if it needs to be called after the state update is complete or not. But assuming it needs to operate the same as your given code, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

- So a main difference between Class this.setState and functional component updating the state using the second parameter returned from useState is that it doesn't merge the state but replaces it. So if you have a lot of props in a component make sure to declare a state for each one of them instead of grouping them in a single useState - it makes it easier for you to manage.

**However, unlike this.setState in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.**
Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

- As for triggering the callback function use useEffect hook which get's triggered when it's dependencies change - in the example provided below the inputToOutput function will be triggered once (sortalphaStatus or sorttypeStatus) are changed. The way you tried to do it won't work since the useState second param does not accept a callback https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html (search for `setState(newState);`).

E.g

`[num, setNum] = useState();`

setNum function accepts only a new value setNum(5), additional params are not taken into account.

```
setNum(5, () => console.log('potato'));
```

potato will never be logged in the console.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const inputToOutput = () => null;

export const TestComponent = () => {
  const [sortalphaStatus, setSortalphaStatus] = useState('A-Z');
  const [sorttypeStatus, setSorttypeStatus] = useState('alpha');
  
  const handleSortAlpha = () => {
    setSortalphaStatus(sortalphaStatus === 'A-Z' ? 'Z-A' : 'A-Z');
    setSorttypeStatus('alpha')
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    inputToOutput()
  }, [sortalphaStatus, sorttypeStatus])

  return <div onClick={handleSortAlpha}>test</div>
};`
```